# Setting the resource of an ImageView using a CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-sqlite, simplecursoradapter

Sorry for such an open-ended question, but I'm new to Android and I genuinely looked all over for an answer and couldn't find anything. I'm wanting to store some sort of information that references an image in a SQLite table, and then use a SimpleCursorAdapter to move that data to an ImageView. I thought that, if I store an integer (the resource ID) and then have the adapter set to the correct view, the resource of the view would be updated to that ID, but that didn't work. Is there any other way to do what I'm wanting to do?

Thanks in advance :)

Edit 1:
This is what I'm doing right now. I'm storing the drawable's ID in the table and then setting the  SimpleCursorAdapter to a View whose resource I want to be the drawable. Here's the code I use to store the info:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(SubwayContract.ROUTE_IMG, R.drawable.red_circle);
values.put(SubwayContract.ROUTE, "R");
values.put(SubwayContract.FINAL_STATION, "Howard-Bound");
values.put(SubwayContract.ARRIVAL_TIME, "5:24:00");
final Uri uri = mContentResolver.insert(SubwayContract.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

The second line stores the image ID. Here's the code I have that sets the adapter:

```
private final int URL_LOADER = 0;
private String[] mProjections = {SubwayContract._ID, SubwayContract.ROUTE_IMG, SubwayContract.ROUTE, SubwayContract.FINAL_STATION, SubwayContract.ARRIVAL_TIME};
private int[] mTo = {R.id._id, R.id.arrival_icon, R.id.arrival_letter, R.id.arrival_dest, R.id.arrival_time};
private SimpleCursorAdapter mAdaptor = null;
...
getLoaderManager().initLoader(URL_LOADER, null, ArrivalsFragment.this);

    ListView mListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.arrivals_list_view);
    mAdaptor = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            rootView.getContext(),
            R.layout.arrivals_list_item,
            null,
            mProjections,
            mTo,
            0
    );
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdaptor);
```

The View's ID is R.id.arrival_icon, which is a View. I know that there's no error in the cursor or the loader, as everything works fine if I take out the View and ID. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can save resource Id of the image (which is in `drawable` folder) into database.
You can try as below:

```
int resID = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(image_name, "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
```